# Adicionar label em um Container no Flutter

Tags: label, flutter

Gostaria de adicionar uma label como a da imagem abaixo na borda de um container, o código do meu container é esse:

```
new Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.black26))
```

Alguma ideia de como posso fazer isso?

[image: Label]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Solução que encontrei foi adicionar no Child do Container um `InputDecorator`, assim podendo estilizar qualquer objeto dentro do container como é os textField do meu App.
Dentro do child do `InputDecorator` adiciono o `widget` que vou utitilizar, e depois adiciono no `Decoration` do `InputDecorator` a borda e a label que quero, deixando-o assim da forma que eu queria.

```
        child: Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: InputDecorator(
          child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
            child: new DropdownButton(
              value: itemSelected,
              onChanged: (String newValue) {
                setState(() {});
              },
              hint: new Text("Selecione"),
              isDense: true,
              items: <String>['  ', 'Sim', 'Não']
                    .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
          return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: value,
          child: Text(value),
          );
          })
              .toList(),
            ),
          ),
          decoration: new InputDecoration(
              contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(11.0),
              labelText:(this.label != null ? this.label : ""),
              enabledBorder:  OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: borderColor()
                ),),
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black)))),
    ));
```

Answer (score -1):

voce pode desativar a borda simplesmente usando enabledBorder: InputBorder.none dentro do InputDecoration ex:

```
TextFormField(
 decoration: InputDecoration(
 labelText: 'Email',
 enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,// isso que vc quer para desativar a borda
 labelStyle: TextStyle(
 color: Colors.white,
 fontSize: 15.0,
  ),
 ),
),
```